# Python: Concatenate columns based on "\"

Tags: python, newline, concatenation, string-concatenation

I've recently received a .csv data frame from a database that was supposed to return 4 columns but actually returned 8. When I checked, I found that some columns have been added because it seems like the string that belonged in the fourth column had a newline in it.

In other words, I'm seeing something like this:

```
index  A  B    C         D      (extra)   (extra)  (extra)  (extra)
  0    1  2  'abc\'    'def\'    'ghi\'    'jkl\'   'xyz'   some_date
  1    1  2  'abc'    some_date
  2    1  2  'abc\'    'def'    some_date
```

As opposed to this:

```
index  A  B         C                D
  0    1  2  'abcdefghijklxyz'   some_date
  1    1  2       'abc'          some_date
  2    1  2     'abcdef'         some_date
```

Is there an efficient way to combine columns that end in a newline with the column to the right?

Comment: Can you clarify "combine columns that end in a newline with the column to the right"? Can you show us a sample of the CSV?

Comment: Fixing such .csv looks like a simple task. You can just replace \'    ' with nothing. Or if don't know the number of space, you may use regexp '\ +'. I would preprocess a file using sed or just do the replacement in a gui text editor that supports regexp, instead of using python.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
First you need to extract the column `'D'` which has been split up and put at the end of non-empty values for each row. Additionally each of the values from `'D'` should be removed from their current positions. You can do this with a loop like this:

```
import pandas as pd

D_col = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    # get the index of the last non-empty/null value in the row
    d_idx = next(j for j,x in reversed(list(enumerate(row))) if x)
    # put the value at that index in D_col
    D_col.append(row[d_idx])
    # replace that value with ''
    row.iloc[d_idx] = ''
```

This will remove the `some_date` values from your DataFrame and put them in the list `D_col`.

**Step 2:**
Now you can use `str.replace` to remove the slashes and `str.cat` to join the columns. Here's an example:

```
from functools import reduce

columns_to_join = ['C', 'D', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3']
# first remove the slashes
cleaned_columns = [df[col].fillna('').str.replace('\\', '') for col in columns_to_join]

# create an empty Series to start reduce with
empty_series = pd.Series(['' for _ in range(len(df))])
# iterate over the cleaned columns and join them (using str.cat) into one column
C_col = reduce(lambda acc, col: acc.str.cat(col.fillna('')), cleaned_columns, empty_series)
```

**Step 3:**
Bring all this together into one, final DataFrame. Here's how:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df[['A', 'B']])
new_df['C'] = C_col
new_df['D'] = D_col
```